# <h:messages> not displaying the facesContext messages

Tags: jsf, exception

i have ErrorPage.jsp in which i have

```
<h:messages styleClass="messageError" id="messages1"></h:messages>
```

when an Exception occurs in a backing beans constructor i catch it and i do the following

```
public constructorxxx throws Exception{
    // code 
// code 
// code
catch(Exception e){
try{
        LOG.error(e);
        String customMessage = "An Unknown Error At " + e.getStackTrace()[0].toString() +  "at" + message;

        getFacesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                customMessage, null));
throw new Exception();
                }catch (IOException exception){   
            LOG.error(exception);   
    } 
}
} // end of constructor
```

in my Web.xml i used the following  tag.

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
<location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
```

when i do that i get the following errors

```
1) Uncaught service() exception root cause Faces Servlet: javax.servlet.ServletException
2) An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/sc00/ErrorPage.jsp] in application [MembershipEligibilityScreensEAR]. Exception created : [java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found.

and in my page it displays as
SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: Faces Servlet
Error Stack: 
java.lang.Exception 
// stack trace


Error Message: java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found
Error Code: 0
Target Servlet: 
Error Stack: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found
```

Many people asked me to change the location of the ErrorPage.jsp as /sc00/ErrorPage.faces but it shows a broken link warning on my web.xml and the error is webpage cannot be displayed and programming error.

I am using jsf 1.2 and my "ErrorPage.jsp" doesn't have a backing bean.

can anyone suggest me why the the Error.jsp is not being displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faces messages are request scoped, so they have the same lifetime as the current HTTP request-response cycle. However, you're instructing the webbrowser to create a new HTTP request by sending a redirect. The faces messages are not there anymore in the new HTTP request.

You'd better just throw an exception and associate the particular error page with the particular exception by `<error-page>` entry in `web.xml`. The servletcontainer will automatically forward to the particular error page within the same request.

E.g.

```
getFacesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, customMessage, null));
throw new SomeException();
```

with

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.example.SomeException</exception-type>
    <location>/sc00/ErrorPage.faces</location>
</error-page>
```

But given that your particular container and JSF impl/version apparently can't forward to a JSF based error page (is it running in an infinite loop?), then your best bet is to remove all JSF components from the error page (otherwise you will get `RuntimeException: FacesContext not found`) and make it a really plain vanilla JSP page with only HTML and JSTL.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.example.SomeException</exception-type>
    <location>/sc00/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

You should only put the message in the exception itself instead of adding as faces message.

```
throw new SomeException(customMessage);
```

Then, you can display it in the error page as follows:

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}
```

You could even just let the exception go (i.e. just redeclare it as `throws` in action method.

```
public void doSomething() throws SomeException {
    // ...
}
```

The servletcontainer will automatically log it anyway.

Comment: As you said, i did add <error-page> <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type> <location>/sc00/ErrorPage.jsp</location> </error-page> to the web.xml and threw Exception in the code. But i am facing the same problem like i used to before, its giving me Error Message: 1) javax.servlet.ServletException Error Code: 500 2) [java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found and the error page was not displayed.

Comment: you said so many times to me to change the location path to /sc00/ErrorPage.faces. If i do that then i am getting a warning in the web.xml saying "brokenLink". Previously you reprimanded me for posting duplicate questions, but i am still facing the same problem. please help me i can post you the complete web.xml

Comment: Your best bet is probably to remove all JSF components from the error page and throw the exception (instead of adding a faces message) and use `${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}` to display the exception message.

Comment: i modified the question, can you have a look at it and if anything striked your mind please reply

Comment: i cannot remove the componenent from jsf page because most of the employees here add faces messages and display them. i am unable to fix the problem. is there any ways that i could add a listener to jsf lifecycle and handle the errors.

Comment: Create and use a dedicated error page for the specific exception.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bauke, its working if i remove all the jsf components from the jsp and making it a plain html page. As you said if the jsf components are present its getting into an infinite loop, do you have any idea why jsf 1.2 and websphere 8 has this problem.